# How to execute and get input of cursor in popup?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want create a `cusrsor` in oracle sql developer in which it shows employee report according to input popup `salary` amount.

I have created cursor but i don't know how to run this cursor and how to get my input using popup from user?

```
declare
cursor c_emp is
select FIRST_NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID from EMPLOYEES where 
SALARY>=10000;
v_name EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
v_sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%type;
v_deptno EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%type;
 begin
 open c_emp;
    loop    
        fetch c_emp into v_name, v_sal, v_deptno;
        exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
    end loop;
  close c_emp;
  end;
```

How to execute `cursor` and get salary input from user in popup?it will show each employee report.

Comment: plsql and oracle-sqldeveloper both are same,i am using oracle-sqldeveloper software

Comment: according to google `PL/SQL is Oracle Corporation's procedural extension for SQL and the Oracle relational database` and oracle-sqldeveloper is software i am using

Comment: Yes. But PL/SQL Developer is an tool written by Allround Automations, a third party supplier, to help developers write PL/SQL. The reason I am labouring the point is because questions about user interaction depend heavily on the tools the user is working with. Properly tagged questions lead to more timely answers. In this case, the tag you were looking for is the generic `[plsql]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Developer supports many (but not all) of the venerable SQL*Plus command set. The supported set includes the `&` syntax for identifying substitution variables. A substitution variable is a placeholder which prompts the user for input when they run the code.

So what you need to do is edit your code to use this:

```
declare
  cursor c_emp is
    select FIRST_NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID 
    from EMPLOYEES
    where SALARY >= &min_salary; -- substitution variable

  v_name EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
  v_sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%type;
  v_deptno EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%type;
begin
 open c_emp;
    loop    
        fetch c_emp into v_name, v_sal, v_deptno;
        exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
    end loop;
  close c_emp;
end;
```

This will prompt the user to enter `min_salary` when they run this program. In Oracle SQL Developer you run this code like any other statement <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> or clicking the green arrow on the menu bar.

Substitution variables are placeholders: they are not stored in an addressable space. If you want to do that for any reason, you need to explicitly defined variable and assign the substitution variable to it:

```
l_min_salary number := &min_salary;
```

Then you would need to change the rest of the code to use that variable. Maybe like this:

```
declare
  cursor c_emp (p_min_sal number) is
    select FIRST_NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID 
    from EMPLOYEES
    where SALARY >= p_min_sal; 

  l_min_salary number := &min_salary;-- substitution variable

  v_name EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%type;
  v_sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%type;
  v_deptno EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%type;
begin
 open c_emp (l_min_salary);
    loop    
        fetch c_emp into v_name, v_sal, v_deptno;
        exit when c_emp%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_name||' '||v_sal||' '||v_deptno);
    end loop;
  close c_emp;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @APC but where `min_salary` stored in which variable and also let me know how can i execute this cursor in `oracle sql developer` software???